# Is it practical to make home-made membrane switches in low quantities?

Tags: switches, button

I'd like to custom-make membrane keyboard switches as a replacement for the cheap push buttons I am currently using. You have all seen these kinds of buttons. If you have experience making these membrane keyboard switches, can you shed some light on that? Or if it's really something that should only be done in a large manufacturing environment, let me know. Alternatives are just as well - I appreciate it.

EDIT AFTER ANSWERS 
i am considering capacitative switches after review of methods used to make membrane switches,  as i am not sure whether the membrane switches i can produce are of professional quality. as an alternative, there is a capacitative switch in my lamp ( these act as a proximity sensor almost.. detecting the capacitance change , from the human body, interacting on the switch) i hover my finger over a solid transparent plate where the switch is under and then it switches. This may be a more consistent, quality way to switch the power.

the switch uses a transparent solid plate.. then a decal over it, then another transparent solid plate. Where the switch (sensor switch) detects my movement is left transparent.

Comment: have you considered capacitive switches?

Comment: i have considered these capacitative switches since reading trhough the asnwers here - i am updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to make them, start with either a flexible PCB or a rigid PCB depending on your application, then fit a spacer sheet usually out of a soft plastic, this way the sticker does not need to stretch around the bump caps, with holes cut in it for the buttons place the bump caps in the holes, and lastly the decal over the top to hold it all in place.

The better the adhesive you use, the better the final product,

Have made a short run of 5 in the past, the better the adhesive, the better the end result, and you want that spacer to be slightly thinner than the bump caps, about the average of the idle and depressed states, I believe I used the clear covers off a plastic school folder for the spacer, and very thin 3M tape, I'm afraid I do not remember the decal material, It was cut on a vinyl cutter, but believe it was a different material.

I have had a look, but sadly am unable to find any photos from that project.

Answer (score 2):

There's a 'metal snap dome' style button that you can use which simply sits loose on the keypad. It can be held in place with adhesive, in a membrane, or with some kind of a housing. This overlays your PCB with the contact pattern.

They give a nice tactile feel without consuming a lot of height. And because their placement is defined by the PCB, button arrangement is easy to customize.

Keystone (and a billion other places in China) make them. Here they are on Digi-key for reference: https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/k/keystone/metal-key-pad-dome-switches.

Here's more description of their application: https://www.sager.com/manufacturers/keystone-electronics/metal-key-pad-dome-switches-from-keystone/

Comment: you'll want nickel plating on the surface of the board for best results.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical keys are actually much cheaper and easier to DIY as an individual despite their reputation as being expensive and high end for consumer products.

It's just because the discrete nature of mechanical keys makes them expensive per unit, but you have no setup costs. All you have to do is buy each key pre-made. This makes them good for low quantities but means they don't lend themselves as well to cheap mass production as membranes which have very high setup costs but you can churn a million of them out at much cheaper cost per unit.

Plus the discrete nature of mechanical keys makes them well suited for DIYer since it comes in discrete components that you can arrange together however you need, whereas a membrane keys all come together integrated onto one big piece so what you have is what you get and useless for repurposing into another arrangement (which means they always need to be custom, more or less).

Or just search Grayhill, Apem, Digikey, or Mouser for pushbuttons if you need pushbuttons and not keyboard keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could some conductive ink and polycarbonate sheeting and apropriate connectors  and have a go for yourself.

However for the price of the ink I can buy hundreds of tactile switches (at less than 1c each).